# desoldering a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, soldering

Ddesoldering a capacitor: On board we have a power supply unit requiring replacing capacitors 1000uF 50V. Although its showing 0v (i.e. have been discharges and unit has been isolated from the main board but still capacitor joint does not meelt. I also used wick flux wire to to desolder. Do I need higher temp? I have 40W iron that normally works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is it soldered onto big planes? The heat is probably being dissipated too quickly. You may need a more powerful iron.

Comment: A photo says more than thousand words. 40W is a bit small for a lot of bigger solder joints.

Comment: What temperature is the iron? Is there a huge ground plane on one side of the capacitor? Is your iron looked after? There are a few things that can have an effect, may be an idea to add some pictures

Comment: Did you use this iron to assemble the board originally? If it's a commercial board, it was probably wave-soldered, which involves a whole lot more power.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming through-hole, demolish the cap with cutters where you have only two individual leads to remove.